# Match just one word among specific others with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a Python script that looks for a phrase (1 to 5 words) in a text. 
I want to allow other words to be among the ones of the phrase I'm looking for, and I was trying to use regex for such task.

Say my phrase is

```
p = "red blue green"
```

and I want to allow JUST ONE any other word to be among them and still got a match:

`t1 = "this is a red blue green flower"` should be a match

`t2 = "this is a red blue yellow green flower"` should be a match

`t3 = "this is a red violet blue yellow green flower"` should be a match

`t4 = "this is a red blue yellow and green flower"`should NOT be a match

Which is the regex for that?

Comment: Or without `re`: `any(w in t for w in phrase.split())`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Will match this too: "this is red foo bar foo blue bar green"

Comment: You wish to check the occurance of those words and neglecting the word 'and'? Could be great if you could provide 2 more test cases for not matches

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Apparently, their question is not clear.

Comment: @Fed, is this what you're looking for? https://regex101.com/r/s2FbHZ/3

Comment: @TrishantPahwa @Moses Basically I want to count the occurrences of `p` in a corpus. But it should not be greedy: there can be AT MOST ONE other word between any pair of words in `p`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks it works ! :)

Comment: @Fed Want me to create an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to get the corresponding regex pattern if the order `red, blue, green` is always respected:

```
markers = "red blue green".split()

pattern = r'\b'+ ' (\w+ )?'.join(markers) + r'\b'
print(pattern)
# \bred (\w+ )?blue (\w+ )?green\b
```

Here's a small test:

```
t1 = "this is a red blue green flower" 
t2 = "this is a red blue yellow green flower" 
t3 = "this is a red violet blue yellow green flower" 
t4 = "this is a red blue yellow and green flower"

import re
print(re.search(pattern, t1))
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ff0a72741c8>
print(re.search(pattern, t2))
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ff0a72741c8>
print(re.search(pattern, t3))
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7ff0a72741c8>
print(re.search(pattern, t4))
# None
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!